# Vega-Lite: Access nested fields of repeat channel

Tags: vega-lite

I would like to visualize the median of some data over time with three error bands for different quantile ranges (spanning between percentiles: 5 to 95, 10 to 90, and 25 to 75). A naive solution for this would be to to specify the three layers manually (which works fine). However, I can't find a way to specify this in a less verbose manner via `repeat`.

How can I make use of the repeat channel in this example:

```
{
    "repeat":{
        "layer":[
            {"low":"p5", "high":"p95"},
            {"low":"p10", "high":"p90"},
            {"low":"p25", "high":"p75"}
        ]
    },
    "spec":{
        "mark":{"opacity":0.15, "type":"errorband"},
        "encoding":{
            "x":{"field":"time"},
            "y":{"field":{"repeat":"layer.low"}, "type":"quantitative"},
            "y2":{"field":{"repeat":"layer.high"}}
        },
        "layer":[{"mark":{"type":"line"}, "encoding":{"x":{"field":"time"}, "y":{"field":"p50"}}}]
    }
}
```

Of course, this does not work since `layer.low` is not a repeat channel. There is only the `layer` channel.

1. How can I access the nested fields of this repeat channel (`low` and `high` for each layer)?
2. Is there some kind of "best practice" how to specify a repeated view over *pairs* of fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repeat.layer` accepts [only a list of strings](https://github.com/vega/schema/blob/ddc684b26ca98fac9cd29de6cd86b6ea03a77d95/vega-lite/v4.9.0.json#L9998-L10004), not a list of nested objects. The Vega-Lite grammar does not currently provide any natural way to express what you want to do via a repeat operator. The best approach would be to manually layer your charts.